# How to avoid blackboxing function output in bash?

Tags: bash

If I have a bash script that is purely made of functions, how do I get things like prompts to show up in the terminal? For example, consider the following:

```
prompt() {
  read -p "This is an example prompt. [Y/n]"
}

main() {
  prompt
}

main "$@"
```

How do I get that prompt message to show up in the terminal? When I just call prompt() from main(), it blackboxes the whole prompt() function. Do I have to return something from prompt()? What if I want to echo a bunch of messages after the read in prompt()? How do I get those to show up in the terminal?

I think I'm missing a basic programming concept here.

Comment: Maybe the end user ought to `source` the file full of functions into the current bash process.  It would seem that executing the file instead of sourcing it, and thereby creating a new process, is what raises this question of what to put in `main()`.  If `source` is used then `main` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a script with that code, main will not be executed. An alternative is to leave prompt() as a function, and move the functionality of main() outside of the function.

```
prompt() {
  read -p "This is an example prompt. [Y/n]"
}

prompt
```

If you would like to keep main as a function, then you will have to source the file, and then call main.

```
$ source file.sh
$ main
```

where file.sh is the file with your code, and $ denotes the terminal prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to last question 1st. Yes, 'shell' is executed linearly (functions must appear before they are called and only get executed when called) and main is not automatically called.

The default variable for a `read` is $REPLY unless you supply your own variable(s), so:

`echo $REPLY`

or

`read -p "Enter data?" MYVAR;    echo $MYVAR`

or

`read -p "Enter data?" FIRSTVAR RESTOFSENTENCE;    echo $FIRSTVAR:$RESTOFSENTENCE`

if you want to do more stuff after your "main", you can just add those commands in the sequence you want them to occur either inside of main (provided that main is called) or after the call to main

if you want them to just be functions, you can save them to a file called myfuncs.sh and then from a shell source that and run a function(s):

`. myfuncs.sh && main`

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing the script, and what's calling main()?

Bash scripts aren't like C programs and don't require a main() function.  Bash will "remember" any functions it sees, but you actually need to call them directly from the script.

Try this:

```
# Start of script
prompt() {
  read -p "This is an example prompt. [Y/n]"
}

prompt
# End of script


bash$ chmod +x script_name
bash$ ./script_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you type prompt instead of prompt()

better is...

```
function prompt() {
  read -p "$* [Y/n]"
}
```

then

```
prompt "This is an example prompt."
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is this:
*You have a set of functions (of bash shell scripting) and you want them to return values to the calling points.*

Example in C++:

```
char * prompt() {
    std::cout<<"Some message:";
    std::cin>>value;
    return value;
}
```

This kind of return values are **impossible** in the bash(or other bourne descendant shells) scripting. Functions only have an exit value(similar to commands), for example, an implementation of the `false` command:

```
myfalse() { return 1; }
```

Thus `return` only sets a zero or nonzero exit status.

To use a value from a function, the function needs to put the value to standard output and that output captured via command substitution. For example:

```
toupper() {
    val="$(echo $1| tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')"
    echo $val
}

ucasestr="$(toupper "Hello, World")"
echo $ucasestr
HELLO, WORLD
```